# How can I make a Enso style application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-xp

The background should be transparent, but the text should not.

Comment: How about elaborating on that is meant by 'Enso' ?

Comment: try http://www.humanized.com/enso_demo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enso is open source too.

You can directly peek at they source code.

http://code.google.com/p/enso/

Let us know how they do it when you find out!.

**UPDATE**

It looks like they use something called Cairo. If you can link it from C# you're done.

Answer (score 1):

By making an "Enso style" application you mean the Enso launcher?

Here is a screenshot of it:
[alt text http://enscreenshots.softonic.com/s2en/68000/68880/3_ensolauncher03.jpg](http://enscreenshots.softonic.com/s2en/68000/68880/3_ensolauncher03.jpg)

I would suggest at looking at the open-source C# [Cropper](http://www.codeplex.com/cropper) application.  He does a similar looking GUI with transparent background.  You can open up his project and see how he implements it.

[alt text http://img352.imageshack.us/img352/726/cropperuijt3.png](http://img352.imageshack.us/img352/726/cropperuijt3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color, and transparency key properties to the same color and that will make the background transparent.  The rest of the control items will stay non-transparent, as long as they are different colors.